# How and where to call a method in a Class based view Django

Tags: django, django-views

As part of a News Years resolution, I have promised to myself that I would learn to write Class Based Views, but as it turns out, I need some help..

What I am trying to do is call a method that generates a random number and then sends an email before the page loads, which I comfortable doing (I'll probably use celery to send the mail in the background).

What I don't understand is how and where to call the methods random_code() and send_email() (see below)?

Do I do this by overriding setup(), dispatch() or get() etc?

Can someone please give me a basic example of what to do?

The class is going to look something like this:

```
class VerifyCode(FormView):

    template_name = "account/verify.html"
    form_class = VerifyForm

    def random_code(self):
        #random_code generator
        return random_code

    def send_email(self):
        #code to send email
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to render random number inside your email template or you want to send random number to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which REST method do you want to call it. If you are using simple `GET`, then call it in `get()` like this:

```
class VerifyCode(FormView):

    template_name = "account/verify.html"
    form_class = VerifyForm

    def random_code(self):
        #random_code generator
        return random_code

    def send_email(self):
        #code to send email

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.random_code()
        self.send_email()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In similar way in `post()` for `POST` method.

Another thing is you can send emails directly with `Django`. I do that and it's pretty simple. [Check this DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/). You can post another question about that if you have something.

Comment: Many thanks Nixon, I suppose I would finish the get method off with:  return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)?

Comment: Yes, definitely. In this way you would not interfere with original `get`. Edited just to make it clearer. But `return render(request, self.template)` should work too if somehow needed.